# Spring Batch using Sybase IQ data source

Tags: spring, sybase, spring-batch, apache-commons-dbcp, sap-iq

How do we properly configure Sybase datasource in a Spring Batch?

Currently I am using a JdbcPagingItemReader for reading DB and creating the data source using Tomcat DBCP. However the following error occurs on the batch run.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Sybase IQ]
at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromProductName(DatabaseType.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:108)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:162)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:82)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
... 13 more
```

For reference, I am currently JConn4-7.0 jar for connectivity. There are no issues connecting to a Oracle Database though [with pool properties changed for Oracle].

Any insight would be helpful.

Please feel free to edit the question for clarity/readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is probably from not explicitly configuring the database type on your JobRepositoryFactoryBean.  Without it set, we attempt to determine what type it is from the JDBC metadata.  To explicitly specify Sybase as your job repository's database type, configure it via the databaseType attribute on the JobRepositoryFactoryBean like below:

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="SYBASE" />
</bean>
```

You can read more about this feature in the Spring Batch documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository

Comment: +1. Surprised I didn't find it before though I was looking for a param to set it [used annotation based configs]. I will check it & mark ✓

Comment: I am currently using MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean for the jobRepository; hence it doesn't have a databaseType [since inMemory]